# Wordpress 404 error page while saving very long post

Tags: wordpress, post, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with saving a **very long post**. When I try to save or preview it, it loads in 3 to 4 seconds and then it returns a 404 error. I am able to insert the post data directly to my mysql database and display the page this way, but when I try to edit and preview it, it still returns 404. When I shorten the post data and try to save it it works as expected.

What the issue here ? Apache httpd.conf ? PHP php.ini ? .htaccess ?

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you working locally or on a live enviroment?

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-posts-returning-404-error/ check this out

Comment: I am using both but I have problem with live env thx.
Local simse to work fine

Answer (score 0):

you wil need to increase max_input_vars config option, which is defaulted to a value of 1000.

Open the PHP.INI configuration file and add these lines

[suhosin]

max_input_vars = 20000(value as per your requirement)

suhosin.post.max_vars = 20000(value as per your requirement)

suhosin.request.max_vars = 20000(value as per your requirement)